# How do I add labels to each of my lines in the line graph?

Tags: html, json, d3.js, visualization, linechart

The below is the code to create my line chart and I would like to add on labels to each of the lines in the line chart but I have no idea on which properties to add into the codes. So, is there anyway for me to add in the labels into the lines?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .x.axis path {
      display: black    ;
    }

    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;

    }

    h3 {
      margin-left:220px;
    }
    .d3-tip {
      line-height: 1;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 12px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 2px;
    }
    </style>
    <div>
        <h3>Life Expectancy History</h3>

    <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
        <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
    <script>
    var margin = { top: 30, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
            width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>Year:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.year + "</br><strong>Male:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.male + "%" + "</span></br><strong>World Rank:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.rankmale;
      });

    var tip1 = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>Year:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.year + "</br><strong>Female:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.female + "%" + "</span></br><strong>World Rank:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.rankfemale;
      });

    var tip2 = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>Year:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.year + "</br><strong>Both Gender:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.both + "%" + "</span></br><strong>World Rank:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.rankall;
      }); 
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;

        var x = d3.time.scale()
            .range([0, width]);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var y1= d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var y2= d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left").ticks(5);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) { return x(d.year); })
            .y(function (d) { return y(d.male); });

        var line2 = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) { return x(d.year); })
            .y(function (d) { return y(d.female); });

        var line3 = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) { return x(d.year); })
            .y(function (d) { return y(d.both); });     

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        svg.call(tip).call(tip1).call(tip2);

        d3.json("lifehistory.json", function (error, data) {
            data.forEach(function (d)
            {
                d.year   = +d.year;
                d.male  = +d.male;
                d.female = +d.female;
                d.both = +d.both;
            });

            x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
              return d.year;
            }));
            y.domain([60, 85]);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            svg.append("text")      // text label for the x axis
              .attr("x", 265)
              .attr("y", 240)
              .style("text-anchor", "middle")
              .text("Year");

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
              .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Life Expectancy History");

            svg.append("path")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("class", "line")
                .style("stroke", "red")
                .attr("d", line(data));

            svg.append("path")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", line2(data));

            svg.append("path")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", line3(data));

            svg.selectAll('.yaxis1')
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append('circle')
                .attr('class', 'yaxis1')
                .attr('cx', function (datum) {
                return x(datum.year)
                })
                .attr('cy', function (datum) {
                return y(datum.male)
                })
                .attr('r', 3)
                .attr('fill', 'red')
                .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

                svg.selectAll('.yaxis2')
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append('circle')
                .attr('class', 'yaxis2')
                .attr('cx', function (datum) {
                return x(datum.year)
                })
                .attr('cy', function (datum) {
                return y(datum.female)
                })
                .attr('r', 3)
                .attr('fill', 'blue')
                .on('mouseover', tip1.show)
                .on('mouseout', tip1.hide);

                svg.selectAll('.yaxis3')
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append('circle')
                .attr('class', 'yaxis3')
                .attr('cx', function (datum) {
                return x(datum.year)
                })
                .attr('cy', function (datum) {
                return y(datum.both)
                })
                .attr('r', 3)
                .attr('fill', 'blue')
                .on('mouseover', tip2.show)
                .on('mouseout', tip2.hide);
        });

    </script></div>
```

The JSON file I am using.

```
[{"year":"1960","male":"61.7","female":"65.7","both":"63.7","rankmale":"47","rankfemale":"50","rankall":"45"},
{"year":"1970","male":"65.4","female":"70.2","both":"67.7","rankmale":"45","rankfemale":"45","rankall":"44"},
{"year":"1980","male":"68.9","female":"74.2","both":"71.5","rankmale":"33","rankfemale":"36","rankall":"29"},
{"year":"1990","male":"71.9","female":"76.9","both":"74.3","rankmale":"28","rankfemale":"30","rankall":"30"},
{"year":"2000","male":"76.1","female":"80.1","both":"78.1","rankmale":"11","rankfemale":"24","rankall":"15"},
{"year":"2011","male":"80.1","female":"84.6","both":"82.3","rankmale":"6","rankfemale":"8","rankall":"5"}]
```

[image: Line Chart]

Comment: [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) should help.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff What I want for the label is using my own text instead of the columns in the JSON file. So, is there anyway for me to put the labels using my own text?

Comment: Sure, just use your own text instead of `d.name`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Alright I got it thanks alot.